# How to save a file in /usr/local/lib/cnet?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

How can I save a file in `/usr/local/lib/cnet`? I'm trying to save a GIF image in the CNET resource folder to use for a simulation.

It says permission denied, and when I try to `chmod` the folder it gives me the error "not permitted".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need more rights to achieve this.

To be able to `chmod`, try becoming root before doing the call:

```
sudo chmod <YOUR_CHMOD> /usr/local/lib/cnet
```

Comment: correction: sudo chmod <YOUR_CHMOD>
 /usr/local/lib/cnet worked for me. update your answer and I'll check your answer as accepted.